# Tracking redirect domain

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I am hosting my app on heroku and therefore use an `*.herokuapp.com` link. However I have redirected my site with another domain. (plain `www.blablabla.com`) What should I use in my google analytics redirect code?

Does it really matter?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the heroku domain ever seen? Or is it just a redirect instead of going to .herokuapp.com and then clicking to blablabla.com. Because if it is just a redirect and no one will be on .herkuapp.com then you don't need cross domain tracking or need to track the redirect to keep the session in tact.